# Using libavformat to mux H.264 frames into RTP

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, libav, libavformat

I have an encoder that produces a series of H.264 I-frames and P-frames.  I'm trying to use libavformat to mux and transmit these frames over RTP, but I'm stuck.

My program sends RTP data, but the RTP timestamp increments by 1 each successive frame, instead of 90000/fps.  It also doesn't look like it's doing the proper framing for H.264 NAL, since I can't decode the stream as H.264 in Wireshark.

I suspect that I'm not setting up the codec information properly, but it appears in many places in the output format context, so it's unclear what exactly needs to be setup.  The examples seem to all copy codec context info from encoders, which isn't my use case.

This is what I'm trying:

```
int main() {
    AVFormatContext context = avformat_alloc_context();

    if (!context) {
        printf("avformat_alloc_context failed\n");
        return;
    }

    AVOutputFormat *format = av_guess_format("rtp", NULL, NULL);

    if (!format) {
        printf("av_guess_format failed\n");
        return;
    }

    context->oformat = format;

    snprintf(context->filename, sizeof(context->filename), "rtp://%s:%d", "192.168.2.16", 10000);

    if (avio_open(&(context->pb), context->filename, AVIO_FLAG_READ_WRITE) < 0) {
        printf("avio_open failed\n");
        return;
    }

    stream = avformat_new_stream(context, NULL);

    if (!stream) {
        printf("avformat_new_stream failed\n");
        return;
    }

    stream->codecpar->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    stream->codecpar->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    stream->codecpar->width = 1920;
    stream->codecpar->height = 1080;

    avformat_write_header(context, NULL);

    ...
    write packets
    ...
}
```

Example write packet:

```
int write_packet(uint8_t *data, int size) {
    AVPacket p;
    av_init_packet(&p);
    p.data = buffer;
    p.size = size;
    p.stream_index = stream->index;

    av_interleaved_write_frame(context, &p);
}
```

I've even went so far to build in libx264, find the encoder, and copy the codec context info from there into the stream codecpar, with the same result.  My goal is to build without libx264, and any other libs that aren't required, but it isn't clear whether libx264 is required for defaults such as time base.

How can the libavformat RTP muxer be initialized to properly send H.264 frames over RTCP+RTP?

Comment: Re timestamps: you aren't setting any. `AVPacket` has `pts` and `dts` and it is your responsibility to set them to correct values with respect with `AVStream`s timebase (which defaults to 90000). As for framing, you are not setting `extradata` so RTP muxer expects frames in Annex B format. Maybe your codec produces frames in AVCC format?

Comment: Thanks - I will look into the packet pts and dts for the timestamp.  RE: extradata - is this for SPS/PPS?  If the encoder is AVCC, do I need to set a property to support it?  I assume this relates to the bsf/h264_mp4toannexb property when using the command line tool.

Comment: Yes, if output is AVCC then you need to put SPS and PPS to extradata before opening a muxer. I'm not sure if same goes for Annex B too.

Comment: In terms of codecpar, is this where I need to write settings for the muxer, such as H.264?  What is the minimum items that need to be set, codec_type and codec_id?

Comment: codecpar is the place for it. Regarding what needs to be set - it depends on muxer and codec (muxer would set appropriate container-specific headers off this information); the very minimum are codec_type and codec_id. Best of all would be to set everything of course but for RTP and H264 it seems that you only need extradata (to let it know how to parse bitstream).

Comment: I confirmed my frames are coming out as annex B format - **0x0000000167|SPS, 0x0000000168|PPS, 0x0000000165|I-frame**.  I need to figure out (a) whether I still need to put it in `extradata` given it is annex b, and (b) how to generate `pts` and `dts`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128891/discussion-between-danielb6-and-andrey-turkin).